# displaying of files

Tags: windows, command-line

need to find all files with extension .doc off of root of my g drive

Comment: Cool. What OS are you using?

Comment: You forgot to bother specifying your operating system again...

Comment: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the command line:

```
dir g:\*.doc
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your other questions I'll guess you're on Windows. In that case the built-in search tool will suffice. Press the Windows key and `F` to bring up the dialog or open explorer and press "search". Search for filenames containing `.doc` in them on the `g:` drive. If you're on Windows 7, go into the drive and type the `.doc` filter into the top-right search box:

[image]

In the command line, if you want to go in recursively:

```
g:
dir /s /b *.doc
```

Comment: needs to be done in command line format windows

Comment: @kevin: You should be including that sort of information in your question.

Comment: he did ask for the root of the drive only, not recursive search for full drive